# Using localStorage on a to-do list

Tags: javascript

This is my first project without following a video and i am stuck at the final hurdle! I want to save everything to localStorage and retrieve it when the page reloads. i have everything saved in localStorage but am struggling to retrieve it and display it as it was. Here is the code:

```
    let todosArray = [];
const userInput = document.querySelector(".formInput");
const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submitButton");
const completeBtn = document.createElement("input")


// get submit button and log char typed into input and append to Li.
function toDoList() {
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const todoUl = document.querySelector(".toDoList");
    const todoLi = document.createElement("li");

    todosArray.push(userInput.value);
    if (localStorage !== null) {
      localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(todosArray))
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      let storage = localStorage.getItem('todoList');
        if (storage) {
          todoLi = JSON.parse(storage);
        }
        console.log(event);
    });

    todoLi.setAttribute("listItems", userInput.value);
    todoLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput.value));
    todoUl.appendChild(todoLi);
    if (userInput.value.length < 1) return;
    userInput.value = "";

    //append deleteBtn
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");

    deleteBtn.classList.add("deleteBtn");
    deleteBtn.innerHTML = "&times";
    todoLi.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    //apply deleteBtn
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      todoUl.removeChild(todoLi);
    });

    //append completeBtn
    const completeBtn = document.createElement("input");

    completeBtn.classList.add("completeBtn");
    completeBtn.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    todoLi.appendChild(completeBtn);

    //apply completeBtn

    completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      completeBtn.classList.add('lineThrough');
      todoLi.classList.toggle('lineThrough');
    });

  });

};

toDoList();
```

Comment: You seem to be setting the DOMContentLoaded event handler within the button click handler. Isn't it a bit late for that?

Comment: I have tried putting the DOMContentLoaded before the main function starts but it also does nothing.

Comment: You'll need to call toDoList() after you retrieve the list from storage, not immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by adding a function to load the todo array from localstorage:

```
function loadTodos() {
    todosArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')) || [];
}
```

Then call the function somewhere at the beginning of your code.

Then in your `toDoList` function, before defining the event listener, add all the todo items to the DOM:

```
function toDoList(){
    const todoUl = document.querySelector(".toDoList");
    for (var i = 0; i < todosArray.length; i++) {
        const newItem = document.createElement("li");
        newItem.textContent = todosArray[i];
        todoUl.appendChild(newItem);

        /********************************************************
        * This is the same code as you had in the event listener. 
        * Consider extracting it to a separate function to avoid
        * repeating yourself.
        ********************************************************/

        //append deleteBtn
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");

        deleteBtn.classList.add("deleteBtn");
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = "&times";
        newItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        //apply deleteBtn
        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          todoUl.removeChild(newItem);
        });

        //append completeBtn
        const completeBtn = document.createElement("input");

        completeBtn.classList.add("completeBtn");
        completeBtn.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        newItem.appendChild(completeBtn);

        //apply completeBtn

        completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          completeBtn.classList.add("lineThrough");
          newItem.classList.toggle("lineThrough");
        });

        //...your eventListener code for submit button goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `|` instead of `||` ? I've never used that technique before but isn't `||` going to convert implicitly into boolean ?

Comment: `|` and `||` are similiar except that `||` doesn't evaluate the right hand operand when the left hand is false.

Comment: Look at operator precedence. The single one is a bitwise comparison (logical operator) the other one with two pipes (comparison operator) is evaluated only if the first comparator is false.

Comment: @AlexWard what seems to be the problem? You should be able to run this right after `let todosArray = [];`

Comment: and where would it need to be called?

Comment: yes, that's what i have been trying but having no success. I think ill do some more research maybe i will work it out eventually! thankyou for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could put your code in a snippet and I could look at it there?

Comment: not sure if this is easier for you but here is a link to a JSfiddle. the complete button and delete button slightly mess up depending on the size of the result screen as ive not made it responsive yet but the functionality is still there. https://jsfiddle.net/pally1995/povfw631/

Comment: That's cracked it! thanks a lot! just have a few tweaks to do so when it reloads i still get the complete checkbox and the delete button appended to each Li element.

Comment: strange.. ill work it all out tomorrow! thanks for your help tonight.